# convert UIImage to NSString - without using encoding & decoding

Tags: ios

I want to convert the UIImage to NSString without using any encoding and decoding methods. Following code is used.. please guide me.. Here i have used "encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding". But I don't want to use. I want to use the binary directly. is it possible ?

```
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageName];
  NSData *imageDataString = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[imageDataString bytes] length:[imageDataString length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As Toaster said, no it's not possible. You have to use something like base64 encoding which is designed explicitly for the purpose of representing binary data in a string. (As an aside, when you inline embed an image in a html file, you use base64, too, so this seems like a logical solution.)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to save it as a binary file, why don't you just use NSDatas `writeToURL:atomically:` method? If you don't want to save a file - just continue working with NSData. It is an objective-c wrapper around your raw binary data.

Comment: Toastor, Actually I have to convert this binary content into the jsonString and send to the web service. For that I have to convert NSData into NSString with out using any encoding format. is it possible ?

Comment: is the json string part of a http request or are you sending a file? You can't send binary data as part of a http request, you always need some sort of encoding. I had the same problem with one project and solved it using base64 encoding, which is lossless.